# EF6 Code First One to One-Zero

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm trying to configure this relationship but I can't using Code First.

```
EVENT
Id
...
ScheduleId

SCHEDULE
Id
...
Type
EventId
```

An Event will always have an schedule to see its date, place...But a schedule can have an event or not depending the type os schedule. The schedule can be of different types, one of them is event. When the type is event the field EventId will point to the Event.

So I don't want to create a regular one to one relationship where one of the tables is the principal and we use the table Id for the relationship.

In the SQL Server the result has to be:

```
EVENT
FK Event.ScheduleId -> Schedule.Id -> OnDelete NO Action

SCHEDULE
FK Schedule.EventId -> Event.Id -> OnDelete Cascade
```

So when you delete an EVENT, the corresponding SCHEDULE will be deleted, but you can't delete a SCHEDULE if it is "attached" to an Event, you can only delete those SCHEDULES where EventId = null.

I have tried:

```
On EVENT 
HasRequired(p => p.Schedule).WithOptional(a => a.Event).WillCascadeOnDelete(false)

On SCHEDULE
HasOptional(p => p.Event).WithRequired(m => m.Schedule).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But it always takes the EVENT PK Id as a foreing key and that's not what I want.

How can I achieve this configuration using EF Code First?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing a lot of posts I have found the solution.

```
EVENT
Id
...
ScheduleId -> NO
Schedule (Navigation property)

SCHEDULE
Id
...
Type
EventId -> NO
Event (Navigation property)
```

And the options:

```
HasOptional(x => x.Schedule).WithOptionalPrincipal().Map(x => x.MapKey("EventId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

HasOptional(x => x.Event).WithOptionalPrincipal().Map(x => x.MapKey("ScheduleId"));
```

I hope someone finds this interesting and can solve any similar situation.

UPDATED

In fact we just need the following, since EF takes care of the relationship.

```
HasOptional(x => x.Schedule).WithOptionalPrincipal(p => p.Event).Map(x => x.MapKey("EventId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

No need for the other line.